# How to assign a function to an object

Tags: javascript, c#, parsing

How do I assign a JavaScript function parsed from a JSON as a method to a specific C# object?

I am working on a mobile C# client and a JSON file is sent to me from server. I have to parse it to extract a number of different objects specifying GUI which I then render.These objects have various properties and one function operating with them. This function works basically as sort of a GUI trigger. I use Jint library for making the JS function do its magic.
From the JSON file I am able to extract and use the function

```
Engine eng = new Engine();

eng.SetValue("oldValue", oldValue);
eng.SetValue("newValue", newValue);

var returnValue = eng.Execute(MethodInString).GetCompletionValue();
```

but I can't wrap my head around how to declare my C# class so I can pass the parsed function to its instances.

```
class MyGuiClass
{
 /*some properties*/
   public int number_A { get; set; }
   public int number_B { get; set; }

   public object MethodFromJSON(int oldValue, int newValue)
   {
      /* the JSON function should be assigned to this method */
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you extract js function into c#, any example?

Comment: JavaScript is client side, C# is server side. You can't just "assign" a client side function as method of server side object. (at least not out of the box - if you're using some tools/library please share code)

Comment: I guess I didn't clarify it properly.
I am working on a mobile client and the JSON is sent to me from server. I have to parse it to extract a number of different object specifying GUI which I then render.
So this function I get from server works basically as sort of a GUI trigger.

EDIT: I use Jint library for making the JS function do its magic.

Comment: @zmaten Well, yes, your question as it is now is unclear. Please show what you've tried so far, what libraries do you use etc...

Comment: So you expected everyone here to guess all of this? Nice

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly looks like you are looking for how to dynamically invoke C# method. Here is how you can do it.

```
void Main()
{
    var methodFromJson = "MyMethod";
    typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(methodFromJson).Invoke(null, new object [] { 42 });
}

public class MyClass
{
    public static void MyMethod(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("MyMethod. Parameter: {0}", x));
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that method that you are trying to invoke has to be static method.